# Apple TV - route specific app(s) through VPN

Tags: networking, routers, smart-tv

Apple TV does not have support for VPN apps like SurfShark or ExpressVPN like Android.

**The problem**

There is one specific app I would need to go through a specific country. All other apps should not use VPN, just the "usual" network

**Solution idea**

I thought of adding an router in between Apple TV and my home router that would route only requests from a specific app through VPN.

Sidenote: The options like SmartDNS from some VPN providers are not really an options since they always seems to go through a specific country (mostly USA) but I need another country.

**Question**

How to set this up?

Comment: The issue is that once the traffic has left the Apple TV, there is no reliable way to know which app it comes from. You could try to find the servers it uses and filter based on that where you send the traffic, but it’s difficult to be exhaustive and even more to keep that up to date. There could also be location-based DNS responses. So you nearly certainly have to do something on the Apple TV itself if you want to split traffic. Apple supports per-app VPN configurations via MDM on iOS devices, maybe this is also supported on Apple TV? Never tried.